# AngularJs - how to handle multiple events

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular application.on click of a tag, I am populating another div. Now I have a requirement to change the route as well on the click of the tag. how can I do this using Angularjs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call a function on the scope as the click event handler.

For example: In your controller you have

```
$scope.myClickHandler = function() {
  populateDiv();
  changeRoute();
}
```

In your HTML template:

```
<div ng-click="myClickHandler()></div>
```

Comment: And how to change the route inside the changeRoute method?

Comment: You can use $location.path('/newroute');